# How to print the entire model in cvc4 using smtlib

Tags: smt, cvc4

so I have just started to learn [cvc4](https://github.com/CVC4) after I have spent some time learning `boolector`. With it, it is possible to print the model just using [boolector_print_model](https://boolector.github.io/docs/cboolector_index.html#c.boolector_print_model). Unfortunately the doc page for `cvc4` is down at the moment and I cannot understand how to do the same with `cvc4` in Java.

Can anyone help to do it please?

For instance, you could help me to see the model for [this](https://github.com/CVC4/CVC4/blob/master/examples/api/java/LinearArith.java) example.

EDIT: Just to be clear, with the entire model I mean a valid value for each `BV` or in general variable present within my model.

An example model could be:

```
(model
  ...
  (define-fun number_6_0_7 () (_ BitVec 8) #x00)
  (define-fun number_6_1_7 () (_ BitVec 8) #x00)
  (define-fun number_6_2_7 () (_ BitVec 8) #x00)
  (define-fun number_6_3_7 () (_ BitVec 8) #x78)
  ...
)
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Unlike boolector, CVC4 does not have a mechanism of accessing the entire model in once call via the API. This is because CVC4 allows for much richer types, including data-types, uninterpreted-functions, etc.; which makes model construction more complicated.

Instead, you call the `getValue` method for each of the input variables you have, and print them yourself. Here's an example:

https://github.com/CVC4/CVC4/blob/e3cd4670a080554e4ae1f2f26ee4353d11f02f6b/examples/api/java/FloatingPointArith.java#L66-L68

Comment: Thanks @alias, at least I should be able to use the `dump` right? I'm trying it but nothing. I thought that if set to true it should allow me to print the model after every `chdckSat`. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: If you mean the `--dump-models` command line option to CVC4: That's only available when you use CVC4 from the command-line with SMTLib input. There's no equivalent when you use it from the API.

Comment: Via ML I have discovered that there is a printModel() method, https://github.com/CVC4/CVC4/blob/master/src/api/cvc4cpp.h#L3169, there are even examples on how to use it using C++ but not Java. I'm still trying to understand it.. Remember that I'm using the 1.8 and not the latest because the new Java API are not available for that version. Thanks